# incompatible qt lib when running packettracer

Tags: qt, libraries

I am trying to install packettracer on ubuntu 18.04,When I click on the Icon nothing was happening so I ran from shell and gave me `./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Multimedia.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

so I copied the libraries manually from pt to my `/usr/lib` 
[image: Error message], giving this error `Fatal: Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50501) with this library (version 0x50905)
Aborted (core dumped)` 
I read on some questions on different websites that re installing Ubuntu is the only solution, is there another way to fix ?

Comment: Please post text instead of screenshots. And by the way replacing system libraries with libraries from /opt (Cisco is third-party supplier of them) is a **bad idea**. You should revert these changes back to start over. These missed libraries should be installed from APT repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should revert the handmade changes by removing libraries which you have copied to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Multimedia.so.5
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Script.so.5
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5ScriptTools.so.5
```

and so on. **And please do not do such bad things again. You can break your system completely.**

Instead you have to install necessary libraries [from packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libQt5Multimedia.so.5):

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5 libqt5xml5 libqt5script5 libqt5scripttools5
```

and then proceed with running PacketTracer.

Comment: This worked, another Solution I tested on a VM is to download Packet tracer version .3